# How to make a nested field with mixed type options?

Tags: django, form-fields

I'm making a website to manage some kind of schedule.

I looked into calendars and the like and found this form from google's calendar to be quite what I want. [image: Google Calendar Reminder Interface]

The thing is I'm having a hard time figuring out how to solve the `Finaliza` field. 
I have a `Reminder` model, but... Should I make a column for each option and play up with the form widget? 
Is there some canned solution I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just add the columns to your model:

```
finalize_type = models.CharField(choices=(('Never', ''), ('Repetitions', ''), ('Date', '')))
finalize_repetitions = models.IntegerField()
finalize_date = models.DateField()

# model clean!
def clean(self):
     if finalize_type == 'Repetitions':
          # check that there is number in finalize_repetitions
          # raise validation error if not
     elif finalize_type == 'Date':
          # check date on finalize_date

     # You should also check if date and repetions aren't set when type == 'Never'
```

If I remember correctly the model clean fires on save. So if you implement a ModelForm it should be displayed on the forms errors.

I would also implement a method

```
@property
def next_event()
    """returns date of next repetition, None if finished"""
```

Hope it helps.